# Diferentes carpetas en la makefile en c

Tags: c, game, makefile

Estoy haciendo un juego conversacional en c con esta makefile:

```
########################################################
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -g -Wall -pedantic -ansi -std=c99
EJS = game_exe
########################################################
SRCS = game_loop.c game_reader.c game.c graphic_engine.c space.c command.c src/player.c object.c set.c enemy.c
OBJECTS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)
########################################################
.PHONY: clean fclean run runv

all: $(EJS)

$(EJS): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o game_exe $(OBJECTS) -L. -lscreen

clean:
    rm -rf *.o

fclean: clean
    rm -rf $(EJS)

run:
    @echo ">>>>>>Running the GAME"
    ./game_exe hormiguero.dat

runv:
    @echo ">>>>>>Running the GAME"
    valgrind --leak-check=full ./game_exe hormiguero.dat
```

Hasta ahora, creo que he conseguido un Makefile bastante simple, sin embargo ahora me piden las siguientes instrucciones:

> Ficheros con código fuente (.c) en subdirectorio ((./src)). Ficheros de cabecera (.h) en subdirectorio ((./include)). Ficheros objeto (.o) en subdirectorio ((./obj)). Ficheros de librer ́ıas (.a) en subdirectorio ((./lib)).
> Documentaci ́on (generada con Doxygen) en subdirectorio ((./doc)).

Esto me complica bastante la Makefile. Se me ocurre más o menos como hacerlo pero haría una Makefile muy extensa.

¿Podríais decirme maneras eficientes de reescribir mi Makefile con los nuevos cambios sin que quede larga?

(Además si veis algo que sería mejor cambiar en mi Makefile inicial también podríais decírmelo).